# How to get title of current tab

Tags: java, string, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

How would one get the name of the active tab / JPanel within a JTabbedPane in order to compare it to a string? It is a simple question but I cannot find a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

With `getSelextedIndex` you get the index of the active tab and with `getTitleAt` you get the title of that index:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane ...
int selectedIndex = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
tabbedPane.getTitleAt(selectedIndex);
```

Comment: But make sure that selectedIndex  >= 0  before calling getTitleAt().